# multiple listeners for delegate iOS

Tags: ios

I have a class search bar with a delegate didSelectString. I have an class A that implements the delegate and a class B that implements the delegate.

However only the delegate from class A is executed. Can a delegate have multiple listeners? and how do I implement this

Comment: The standard delegate pattern has only one pointer to the delegate object, and hence only one delegate.  You can, however, code the delegate client to maintain an array of delegates, or you can code one delegate to "cascade" to a second.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The delegation is a single messaging protocol. You'll need to use NSNotifications if you want to message multiple objects of a change.

You can pass an object using notifications centre like so:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"myObject" : customObject};

NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"myNotificationString" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

When wanting to listen for notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myCustomObserver:)name:@"myNotificationString" object:nil];
```

And setting up the selector

```
-(void)myCustomObserver:(NSNotification *)notification{
    CustomObject* customObject = notification.userInfo[@"myObject"];
}
```

Comment: can i pass an object with the notification?

Comment: don't forget to call removeObserver when deallocated

Answer (score 3):

You can easily set up a trampoline object that acts as a delegate multiplexer. The idea is to use a proxy object that will stand-in for an array of delegates. When a method is invoked, it will override ***forwardInvocation*** or use ***IMP_implementationWithBlock*** to pass the message on to each of the delegates in the array.

Then all you need to do is add methods: attachListener and removeListener (btw: see how this is starting to get similar to notifications?)

Here's a sample project: https://github.com/aleph7/MultiDelegate

For more information check out the awesome Objective-C Runtime: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: thanks for in-depth answer. Everybody knows NSNotifications, but not all prefer to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Create a small new class called Delegates. Have it adopt the search bar protocol so it can be the primary search bar delegate. Have this class offer a method 'addSearchBarDelegate:', in which it will add the delegate to a mutable array. When it gets a delegate message, it forwards it to each registered delegate.